# How to add a .crt certificate to .net 6.0 api project and enable https?

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, https

i have a project with .NET 6.0, API for website.
I got a certificate today (three .crt files), how to enable https on the project with this?

[certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIF4S.png)

I know that i need to somehow convert this to .pfx, but i cant find information with my case.

Comment: Please show relevant code. What libraries are you using? ASP.Net? `WebClient`? `HttpClient`? Something else?

Comment: It need to be TLS 1.2 or 1.3 compatible.  TLS is sent before the HTTP Request is sent.  The client sends TLS version to server.  The Server than sends a Certificate Block which contains names of certificates.  Then client than looks up the names in the User Stores to find a matching certificate.  All this is automatic. So certificate has to be loaded on both client and server.  It is not in the software unless you specify a certificate name to select a specific certificate.